# Crispy GridLineDashStyle

Tags: highcharts

The gridlines when set to "ShortDot", or any Dots, are always two pixels tall in SVG, and research says it can be fixed via

a) transform(0.5,0.5)  -- moves it half a pixel so drawing is in one pixel,

or

b) add style='shape-rendering:crispEdges' to the  element

See demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aerialflyer/o2d9w6up/

Here's the SVGElement prototype from Highcharts.js

```
SVGElement.prototype = {    
    dashstyleSetter: function (value) {
        var i;
        value = value && value.toLowerCase();
        if (value) {
            value = value
                .replace('shortdashdotdot', '3,1,1,1,1,1,')
                .replace('shortdashdot', '3,1,1,1')
                .replace('shortdot', '1,1,')
                .replace('shortdash', '3,1,')
                .replace('longdash', '8,3,')
                .replace(/dot/g, '1,3,')
                .replace('dash', '4,3,')
                .replace(/,$/, '')
                .split(','); // ending comma

            i = value.length;
            while (i--) {
                value[i] = pInt(value[i]) * this['stroke-width'];
            }
            value = value.join(',')
                .replace('NaN', 'none'); // #3226
            this.element.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', value);
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be updated to include either the transform, or the 'style' (preferred)??

i.e. 
Add
   this.element.setAttribute('style', 'shape-rendering:crispEdges');

Can the SVGElement prototype be updated (fails so far)

```
// Make grid lines crispt to prevent anti-alias
SVGElement.prototype['dashstyleSetter'] = SVGElement.prototype.dashstyleSetter = function (value) {
    var i;
    value = value && value.toLowerCase();
    if (value) {
        value = value
            .replace('shortdashdotdot', '3,1,1,1,1,1,')
            .replace('shortdashdot', '3,1,1,1')
            .replace('shortdot', '1,1,')
            .replace('shortdash', '3,1,')
            .replace('longdash', '8,3,')
            .replace(/dot/g, '1,3,')
            .replace('dash', '4,3,')
            .replace(/,$/, '')
            .split(','); // ending comma

        i = value.length;
        while (i--) {
            value[i] = pInt(value[i]) * this['stroke-width'];
        }
        value = value.join(',')
            .replace('NaN', 'none'); // #3226
        this.element.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', value);
        this.element.setAttribute('style', 'shape-rendering:crispEdges');
    }
};
```

Highcharts Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/aerialflyer/yj1s5xps/

See how dot is just a long gray line

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to extend Highcharts and set shape-rendering to crispEdges (because shape-rendering is attribute set directly, not in style - MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) in dashstyleSetter of SVGElement.

Wrapper:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.SVGElement.prototype, 'dashstyleSetter', function (proceed) {
        // Run original proceed method
        proceed.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
        if(arguments[1]) {
            this.element.setAttribute('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges');
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/yurn5oz5/

[Docs reference for extending Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)